# How can I clean up lua's registry?

Tags: c, lua

If I first place something into the lua's registry table with:

```
int ref = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
```

Then unreference `ref` with:

```
luaL_unref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, ref);
```

and start the garbage collector with:

```
lua_gc(L, LUA_GCCOLLECT, 0);
```

I can still see the `ref` entries in the registry table when I print it up. Why does `luaL_unref` not remove the unreferenced entries, so that the gc could collect them?

Comment: Note that if they're in the registry, then they are still referenced, and the GC won't delete them. A better question would be "why doesn't `luaL_unref` remove the entries". Also be sure that the entries that remain are actually made by your code, and not by some other library.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yes, I've checked and I think the problem is due to optimization concerns in `luaL_ref()/luaL_unref()`.

Comment: Can you add which lua version you did this test on?

Comment: @greatwolf version 5.2. The bug occurs if you add and remove references at random. That is, if you add references to n valus at random and remove the obtained references at random. If you add and remove in reverse order (remove the reference you obtained last first), then it seems to work.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you're describing: http://hastebin.com/azusadolur.cpp. Can you show a self contained example that reproduces this?

Comment: Is your program mutating the array part of the registry in any way? `luaL_ref` assumes it has exclusive access to that and that something else isn't going to come along and clobber its bookkeeping.

Comment: @user1095108: Lua links all holes in the registry ref section in a linked list. So when you unref a value, this table index from now on contains the index of another hole. The previously referenced value is no longer in there, so it can be garbage collected. When you call `luaL_ref` again, you will get an index from that free list (the last unref'ed index not yet reused, actually) until there are no more holes left.

Comment: @greatwolf I'll try to cut out an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @siffiejoe noted in comments, Lua's auxiliary library uses "freelist" mechanism to keep track of free index holes, and that list never shrinks, i.e. its size is always equal to peak allocation — that is size-to-speed tradeoff. You may check the implementation to figure out underlying logic.

If you are sure that no active refs remaining in registry, you may clear integer keys manually (see note below). If you want a completely empty registry, then `lua_newtable(L), lua_replace(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX)` will do that. This is not a good idea though — see comments below this answer.

(Note that you probably can't simply check if all refs were balanced, because some code might ref an integer value. I may be wrong on this though.)

Comment: An empty Lua registry is [not a good idea](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2015-06/msg00527.html), though. (E.g. C libraries get unloaded, the globals table is gone, userdata type checking doesn't work anymore, ...)

Comment: @siffiejoe As of 5.2 globals seem to be a table in registry that is used by auxiliary library... Can you please confirm that brand new Lua state (without openlibs call) does contain LUA_RIDX_GLOBALS pair? If yes, then replacing registry is harmful even for state-reuse needs. (Can't test it myself now.)

Comment: @user3125367 The registry contains the main thread and the globals table from the moment it is created. See [here](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lstate.c.html#init_registry).